# Different output encryption both CryptoJS and Java Code

Tags: java, aes, cryptojs, cbc-mode

I need to encrypt certainly string from client-side (JavaScript) and decrypt from server-side (Java), so I found CryptoJS and I write the code with the same params/configuration of mi Java Code but the output is always different, do you have any idea or what happen?

I'm using **CBC with NoPadding**

**CryptoJS**

http://jsfiddle.net/Soldier/gCHAG/

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js">
</script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/pad-nopadding-min.js"></script>
<script>

    function padString(source) {
        var paddingChar = ' ';
        var size = 16;
        var x = source.length % size;
        var padLength = size - x;

        for (var i = 0; i < padLength; i++) source += paddingChar;

        return source;
    }

    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0123456789abcdef');
    var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('fedcba9876543210');
    var message = "soldier";
    var padMsg = padString(message);

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(padMsg, key, { iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});

    console.log("Encrypted: "+encrypted);
    console.log("Encrypted text: "+encrypted.ciphertext);

</script>
```

**Java Code**

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;

public class AesCipher {

    private static final String algorithm = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";

    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    private static final byte[] ivValue = new byte[] { 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0' };

    private static final IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(ivValue);
    private static final SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");

    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    private static String padString(String source) {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;

        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
        {
            source += paddingChar;
        }
        return source;
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String password = "soldier";
        String passwordEnc = AesCipher.encrypt(padString(password));
        String passwordDec = AesCipher.decrypt(passwordEnc);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
    }

}
```

Original string:

```
soldier
```

Output from CryptoJS:

```
Encrypted: VNzZNKJTqfRbM7zO/M4cDQ==
Encrypted Hex: 54dcd934a253a9f45b33bccefcce1c0d
```

Output from Java Code:

```
Encrypted: j6dSmg2lfjY2RpN91GNgNw==
Encrypted Hex: 6a3664536d67326c666a593252704e3931474e674e773d3d
```

The base64 string encrypted has same length but not the hex.
If I put the output result of CryptoJS in Java Code, the decryption is incorrect.

Regards,

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that you're using 64 bit keys and iv's.

CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256, and AFAIK Java supports AES-128, so you should probably be specifying 128 bit keys and IVs. That might be the whole problem - I'm sure using the wrong key size is undefined behavior.

As for the difference in output lengths, 22 base64 characters is 132 bits of information, so it's a 128 bit answer (There isn't a unique 128 bit length, 21 characters would have been too few).  CryptoJS is outputting 32 hex characters, which is 128 bits of information. This seems correct.

The Java code is outputting 48 hex characters which is 192 bits of information. So it's the java code that's wrong. I'm not sure why it's outputting more, though.